# Beautifulsoup not able to find by String

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this example :

- Url used for practice: "https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=Software-Developer&where=Australia"
- This is the String I am looking for inside a tag : 'Software Engineer - Full Stack - Sydney, New South Wales\n\n'
- I am targeting it with this :

```py
jobs = results.find_all('h2')

print(jobs[0].find("a", string="Software Engineer - Full Stack - Sydney, New South Wales\n\n"))
```

And it returns none. I am guessing it is because of a newline's but i cannot get it to work.

Comment: what exactly you want you want to fetch the string ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `h2` text like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# URL to be scraped
link = "https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=Software-Developer&where=Australia"

# Sending a get request to get the content of page
source = requests.get(link).text

# Parsing with help of bs4
soup = bs(source,"html.parser")

# Extracting the specific element from bs4 object
content = soup.find('h2', {'class': 'title'})

# Getting the desired content
result = content.text

print(result)
```

Output

```
Software Engineer - Full Stack - Sydney, New South Wales
```

To get the string from all titles and match any specific strings.

Add the following code:

```
string = "Software Engineer - Full Stack - Sydney, New South Wales\r\n"
content_one = soup.findAll('h2', {'class': 'title'})
for con in content_one:
    if con.text == string:
        print("Matched!!")
```

To avoid strict matching and ignore the new line, you can check the string in the `h2` text like this:

```
string = "Software Engineer - Full Stack - Sydney, New South Wales"
content_two = soup.findAll('h2', {'class': 'title'})
for con in content_two:
    if string in con.text:
        print("Matched!!")
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer , but I forgot to mention that the purpose of this is to practice how to get the element based on the exact string. In this case that would be find(<Tag>, string="xxx"). Is there a way for this function to work with the given example containing newlines?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Updated my answer to ignore the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to be too specific with the `find` method because it is looking for the exact match

Regarding the BeautifulSoup part, you can refine the `find_all` with the `class` tag to match only the jobs

Here is an example of what you can do :

```
search = 'Software Engineer - Full Stack'

data = results.find_all('h2', class_='title')

for job in data:
    result = job.text.find(search)
    if result != -1:
        print(f"Job found : {job.text[result:]}")
```

Output

```
Job found : Software Engineer - Full Stack - Sydney, New South Wales
```